# Restore menu items using database backup

Tags: database

When working on a site I accidentaly removed all my menu items I now want to recover them from a database back-up I have. Is it enough to just copy all data from these tables from the backup to my sites database?

- menu_link_content
- menu_link_content_data
- menu_link_content_field_revision
- menu_link_content_revision
- menu_tree

Comment: Try it on a local copy of your site. No one knows how you built the items in the first hand, and where the data might have spread to.

Comment: Okay I will test on my local site. I thought the menu would be bundled in the database. Can you give me an example of how a menu link from main menu could be spread somewhere else?

Comment: Some custom/contrib module adding some functionality to the menus storing information somewhere else.

Comment: Ah check! Thanks for the information, this gives me an idea where to look and what to test.